# Implications of the domain of a function in $\Bbb R^3$ to be its projection on a plane?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am currently enrolled in a Calc-3 course and we have begun discussing multivariable functions. Recently in class we considered the function: $$z=f(x,y)=\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}$$

He then stated that the graph of the function is a hemi-sphere in $\Bbb R^3$. In class my professor then stated that the domain of this function on the xy-plane, $z=0$, would be a disk  $$\because z=\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2} \implies D=\{x,y:x^2-y^2\le 9\mid x,y \in \Bbb R\} $$ However I am not fully grasping the meaning of the geometric interpretation of a functions domain. I have attempted searching the internet however the responses are too technical for my current level of understanding.

Here is my exact question:
Does this imply that there could be a function of a hyper-hemi-sphere in $\Bbb R^4$ such that it's domain is a ball, or a sphere, in $\Bbb R^3$? I hope this question is not overly ambiguous and if it is I will certainly attempt to  zero in on a more precise question.

Comment: The function isn't a hemisphere. The _graph_ of the function is a hemisphere.

Comment: Thank you I will change it right now.